# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my controller:

```
namespace Login.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Autherize(Login.Models.user usermodel)
        {

            using (LogEntities db = new LogEntities())
            {
                var userdetails = db.users.Where(x => x.USERNAME == usermodel.USERNAME && x.PASSWORD == usermodel.PASSWORD);
                if (userdetails == null)
                {
                    usermodel.ErrorMessage = "wrong inputs";
                    return View("Index", usermodel);
                }
                return View();
            }

        }
    }
}`
```

this my view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Autherize", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td> Login Form   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USERNAME)   </td>
                <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USERNAME)  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USERNAME)   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PASSWORD)   </td>
                <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PASSWORD)  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PASSWORD)   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> <label class="field-validation-error">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ErrorMessage)</label> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td> <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }

</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

i got this error.how i fix this error?

> The view 'Autherize' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:

Comment: Check LoginController can be parsed through routes. And not sure what you want with loading your View (may not be required)

Answer (score 0):

You have written `return View();` inside the `Autherize` method but you have not created a view page for Autherize (`Autherize.cshtml`) inside `/Views/Login` folder.

You can either create `Autherize.cshtml` view and return it OR redirect to a view which already exists (probably a page to which you want the user to be redirected once they are authorized).

Comment: thank you very much your feedback,in this case i want to display that error message when i give a wrong input.i try your method,i created the Autherize view but i give a wrong input or correct one both time just display the autherize view,not given an error message

Answer (score 0):

Your Get method name is Index so you have to change to Authorize than only it would able to locate your View.

Answer (score 0):

`return View();` statement is trying to find a view based on the method name. Since, you didnt mention any view name. Mention a view name instead.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Autherize(Login.Models.user usermodel)
{
    using (LogEntities db = new LogEntities())
    {
        var userdetails = db.users.Where(x => x.USERNAME == usermodel.USERNAME 
            && x.PASSWORD == usermodel.PASSWORD);
        if (userdetails == null)
        {
            usermodel.ErrorMessage = "wrong inputs";
            return View("Index", usermodel);
        }
        return View('Autherize');
   }
}
```

Comment: i created the Autherize view but that time a cannot get the error message when i give an wrong input,just display Autherize view.

Comment: Try to mention `Autherize` only in the return statement if userdetails is not null i.e., `return View('Autherize')`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Modify your code by this

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Login.Models.user usermodel)
    {

        using (LogEntities db = new LogEntities())
        {
            var userdetails = db.users.Where(x => x.USERNAME == usermodel.USERNAME && x.PASSWORD == usermodel.PASSWORD);
            if (userdetails == null)
            {
                ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "wrong inputs";
                return View("Index");
            }
            return View("Autherize");
        }

    }
```

and change this `@using (Html.BeginForm("Autherize", "Login", FormMethod.Post))` with `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post))`

Then in `Index.cshtml` page

```
@if (ViewData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
   //Write your error message here.
   <h5>User name and password wrong</h5>
}
```

then create `Autherize` view:

```
    public ActionResult Autherize()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If your USERNAME and PASSWORD not null then go to `Autherize` View.

Comment: i did that method but i couldn't get that error message when i give a wrong input.When i give a correct input or wrong input in both time page display login form with display user name, not display that error message.

Comment: I Edited my answer

Comment: thank you for your support.But i want,if i give a wrong USERNAME and PASSWORD then should display my error message.but in this case that not happen,every USERNAME,PASSWORD that i give return Autherize view.How i view error message when i given wrong input.

Comment: I edited my code again. I think now your problem can be solved.